# How is the real number line a second axiom space?

Tags: general-topology

Out of all the stupid questions I may have asked, this surely may be the stupidest. Any help would be appreciated.

My book says *"The real number line is a second axiom space*"

How??

Sure one might say $(-n,n), n\in\mathbb{Z}$ could be described as the sets in the base. But can every open set like $(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ be generated this way? Shouldn't a base be able to generate every open set in a space by taking unions of base sets?

I can't think of any other formulation for a countable base.

I've never dealt with the real number line in topological terms before. My textbook has only minimal algebraic examples until this point. So I'm possiby missing out on something important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** The rational numbers are countable and dense. Therefore $(a,b)$ of the form $a,b\in\Bbb Q$ make a countable basis for the topology.

Answer (score 2):

Take the set of open intervals with rational endpoints. Since this set can be expressed as a countable union of countable sets, it is countable. Verifying that it is a basis of $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology is straightforward.

Comment: Actually a much simpler argument for the countability of this collection is to map an interval to the pair of its endpoints, it's a subset of $\Bbb Q^2$, which is a countable set.

Comment: If I had to represent $(- \sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$, I know that there are rational numbers arbitrarily close to both $-\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2}$. So I create converging sequences $<a_{n}>$ and $<b_{n}>$ converging to both respectively, and assign $(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$ with the open interval $lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{n},b_{n})$. Am I coherent in my argument?